# Measuring suspend function run duration in Kotlin coroutine tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a suspend function like below that does some computation heavy work and has some delay. (In my actual code the delay duration may change depending on the situation).

```kotlin
suspend fun randomNumberGeneratorWithDelay(total: Int) {
    val random = Random()
    repeat(total) {
        random.nextInt()
    }
    delay(1000)
}
```

I want to write a test case for this function in which I calculate overall run time of the function (computation + delay) and do some assertions based on that.

I am trying to utilize the `measureTime()` function from the [Kotlin Coroutines testing package](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test) like below.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
class SimpleTest {

    private val scheduler = TestCoroutineScheduler()
    private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(scheduler)
    private val scope = TestScope(dispatcher)

    @Test
    fun simpleTest() = scope.runTest {
        val workDuration = testScheduler.timeSource.measureTime {
            randomNumberGeneratorWithDelay(10_000)
        }
        // Some assertions for workDuration
    }
}
```

However, `workDuration` is always equal to only amount of the delay in the function. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to measure overall run time of the function in tests?

I am aware that there is normal `measureTime()` function under `kotlin.system` package. But that doesn't skip delays. So to be concrete, I want to skip delays to make the tests run faster yet I want the (supposed) delay values to be included in the overall run time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!